# How to run a stage when a previous specific stage is passed in gitlab

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am new to GitLab ci and trying to create a pipeline.

I have 4 stages
stage_1 --> stage_2 --> stage_3 --> stage_4

I want to run stage_4 only when stage_1 is passed. stage_2 and stage_3 can have any status(skipped/passed/failed) but stage_4 should run only when stage_1 is successful.

I tried with `needs` but that is changing the execution order. I want to preserve the original execution order as well.

Comment: if stage 2 and 3 can fail why wait for them on stage 4?

Comment: because if they pass then I want to use the output files produced by stage_2 and stage_3 in stage_4. If not files are produced then its ok, but if files are present then use them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried specifying needs for each of the tasks, as well using allow failure in stages 2 and 3?

```
stage_1:
stage: stage_1
script:
    - echo "Stage 1 job"

stage_2:
stage: stage_2
needs: 
    - stage_1
script:
    - echo "Stage 2 job"
allow_failure: true

stage_3:
stage: stage_2
needs: 
    - stage_1
    - stage 2
script:
    - echo "Stage 3 job"

allow_failure: true

stage_4:
stage: stage_2
needs: 
    - stage_1 
    - stage_2
    - stage_3
script:
    - echo "Stage 4 job"
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to run stage_3 and stage_4 on failure and on success, you can do this with [when](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when)

```
stages:
  - stage_1
  - stage_2
  - stage_3
  - stage_4

s3_job:
  stage: stage_3
  script:
    - foo
  when: always

s4_job:
  stage: stage_4
  script:
    - bar
  when: always
```